# How to get SublimeText to load DLLs where they load fine using commandline

Tags: python, anaconda, sublimetext3

When using python through the commandline, I am able to import modules fine. However, when I build a python script in SublimeText3, some modules don't import. I generally receive the following error:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

The problem looks to involve modules with dependencies on modules with a "_" prefix (_sqlite3, _ssl). For example:

```
 File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\sqlite3\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\sqlite3\dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

> System:
>
> Windows 10
>
> SublimeText3 (freshly reinstalled during troubleshooting)
>
> Python 3.7.3  [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
>   (freshly reinstalled during troubleshooting)

Both commandline and ST3 or pointing to same instance of Python. 
This is the only python install on the machine.

Have used default Python build in ST3 and created a new build, both have same issue.

Results when using the commandline:

```
Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 17:13:21) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import plotly

>>>
```

Results in ST3:

```
import plotly

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\usr\Desktop\scrap.py", line 1, in <module>
    import plotly
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\plotly\__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    from plotly import (
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\plotly\graph_objs\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from plotly.basedatatypes import BaseLayoutType as _BaseLayoutType
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .callbacks import (Points, InputDeviceState)
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\plotly\callbacks.py", line 2, in <module>
    from plotly.utils import _list_repr_elided
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\plotly\utils.py", line 262, in <module>
    from chart_studio.utils import *
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\chart_studio\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from chart_studio import (plotly, dashboard_objs, grid_objs, session)
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\chart_studio\plotly\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . plotly import (
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\chart_studio\plotly\plotly.py", line 38, in <module>
    from chart_studio.plotly import chunked_requests
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\chart_studio\plotly\chunked_requests\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . chunked_request import Stream
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\chart_studio\plotly\chunked_requests\chunked_request.py", line 4, in <module>
    import ssl
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\ssl.py", line 98, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
[Finished in 2.9s]
```

Any help much appreciated, been stuck on this for days.

Comment: maybe SublimeText is a 32-bit application?

Comment: I used the following installer: Sublime Text Build 3207 x64 Setup.exe

Comment: The problem is unlikely to be based on whether Sublime is 32 or 64 bit because all it's doing is executing an external program. Is there some environment variable of some sort that needs to be set that is perhaps not being properly propagated through Sublime?

Comment: BTW thanks both for our responses. I have checked the sys.path when using ST3 and its comes out the same as when using the commandline. And it specifies the directory where the DLLs are.

Comment: @Odatnurd I thought it might have something to do with the path ST3 uses not including the directory where the DLLs are, but when I look at the sys.path, it includes the directory. On the ST forum you mentioned a similar issue might have to do with using a 3rd party build like Anaconda. Could that be the issue why ST3 is picking up the DLLs?

Comment: Based on the error messages it looks like the errors are being thrown from the code you're importing, so the libraries are being found but they themselves can't find the external DLL's they need. I'm not familiar enough with the underpinnings of Python to know how the interpreter looks for system specific binary libraries, though.

Comment: @OtaNurd Thanks for your thoughts. I think you're right, but couldn't figure out how to get Python to find the DLLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those with a similar issue in the future, I've fixed this by uninstalling the Anaconda distribution of Python and replacing it with a base Python installation from Python.org, then installing packages using pip manually. While not the ideal solution, this has solved the issue so that when I build a Python script in ST3, all modules are imported fine.